# Code works fine until you enter multiple words

Tags: python

For a school project, I've created code that asks the user for an input then asks them to recall a word, then printing that word along with its position in the list. It works fine with single words, but after 2 or more words are added the program carries on to produce an error.

```
sentence = raw_input("Please write a sentence: ")
while "." in sentence or "," in sentence or ":" in sentence or "?" in 
sentence or ";" in sentence:
    print("Please write another sentence without punctutation ")
    sentence = input("Please write a sentence: ")
else:
    words = sentence.split()
    print(words)
specificword = raw_input("Please type a word to find in the sentence: ")
for i in range(len(words)):
    if specificword == words[i]:
        print (specificword, "found in position ", i + 1)
    else:
        print("Word not found in the sentence")
        specificword = raw_input("Please type another word to find in the sentence")
```

With multiple words entered the program still runs

```
else:
    print("Word not found in the sentence")
    specificword = raw_input("Please type another word to find in the sentence")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have *both* if & else inside the `for` loop block, so if it doesn't find your word on the first iteration it immediately goes to the `if` block. You can fix your code by dedenting the `if` block & adding a `break` statement to the `if` block.

```
for i in range(len(words)):
    if specificword == words[i]:
        print (specificword, "found in position ", i + 1)
        break
else:
    print("Word not found in the sentence")
    specificword = raw_input("Please type another word to find in the sentence")
```

Comment: Or, even better: `while any(c in sentence for c in '.,:?;'):`

Comment: The program does run for me in 2.7, this is the result i got.

Comment: Please write a sentence: i love cats
['i', 'love', 'cats']
Please type a word to find in the sentence: cats
Word not found in the sentence
Please type another word to find in the sentence

Comment: Just checked again with your example & it didn't run! So I edited my answer. Also I'm not sure why your interpreter is not complaining about the missing parentheses, but it would make your code a whole lot more readable if you use parentheses or, even better yet, used @gyre's example.